# Opening PDF file from asp.net mvc/script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to open a pdf file by clicking a button/jquery? Does not work.The ActionLink works though?

```
 <h2>
    GetPDF</h2>
<%= Html.ActionLink("works", "GetPDF") %>
<button id="btn">
    does not work
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready()
    {
        $("#btn").click(
        function() {
            var url = "/Home/GetPDF";
            var data = "";
            $.ajax(
        {
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            error: function(err) {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
);
        }

    )
    };

</script>
```

the controller looks like this:

```
       public ActionResult GetPDF()
    {
            string filename = "mypdff.pdf";
            return File(filename, "application/pdf", Server.MapPath("/Content/") + filename);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are making an ajax call. The resulting file is in the ajax object. Perhaps you would like to use `window.location(...)`?

Comment: I completely agree with your assessment, just wanted to add that one could style the link as a button (css inline-block w/ borders, backgrounds, etc.) and possibly achieve the desired effect without JavaScript.